# JSF optional old values come back after clearing them

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, reset, option-type, omnifaces

I am using JSF, PrimeFaces 3.2, Omnifaces 1.1, JBoss AS 7.1.1, Final, Mojarra 2.1.7

I have a form that has two numeric fields both are not required, like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="num1" value="#{bean.field1}"/>
    <p:inputText id="num2" value="#{bean.field2}"/>
<p:commandButton ... ajax="true" />
</h:form>
```

I have also setup  OmniFaces ResetInputAjaxActionListener on faces-config.

The bean properties field1 and field2 are Integer.

Now the issue is if I input say 123 on num1 and input 345 on num2 and click OK all okay.
If I then remove 123 from num1 and put abc on num2. Then validation (conversion) error is shown but 123 comes back!

If I make them both required=true then all is well.

Is there are a way to make this work with optional fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Mojarra specific issue. The field which is being bound to an `Integer` is implicitly been converted by the `IntegerConverter` which converts the submitted empty string value to `null` and sets it as such in the component's local value.

When a form is redisplayed after submit, JSF will first check if the submitted value is not null and then display it, else if the local value is not null, then display it, else display the model value. As the local value is null, the model value is been displayed instead. This is indeed undesired behaviour and has been reported several times:

- [issue 838](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-838)
- [issue 1582](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1582)

This can be fixed by overriding `UIInput#getValue()` as follows:

```
public Object getValue() {
    return isLocalValueSet() ? getLocalValue() : super.getValue();
}
```

[MyFaces](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/refactor_shared_2_1_x/api/src/main/java/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java) already does it right. I've [re-reported](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2536) this issue again which eventually ended up as [spec issue 566](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-566) (**update** and finally fixed in Mojarra 2.2.0 and backported to [2.1.21](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.21/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.getValue%28%29)).

In the meanwhile, the easiest way to workaround this, while taking 3rd party component libraries with their own renderers like PrimeFaces into account, is to copy the source code file of `javax.faces.component.UIInput` class straight in your project's source folder and then add the desired `UIInput#getValue()` method. Yes, a clumsy fix, but there's not really a nicer way as the cause of the problem is deep in the JSF API itself.

The OmniFaces `ResetInputAjaxActionListener` serves an entirely different purpose and isn't designed/suitable to solve this problem. It is supposed to clear the state of input components of which the value of the component is *not* submitted, but the component itself is re-rendered in ajax.

Comment: I forgot to mention  the javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL parameter is set to false

Comment: Right, it's caused by the implicit `IntegerConverter` which is converting `""` to `null` (assuming that those fields are bound to `Integer`)

Comment: Yes they are bound to Integer. So that shouldn't happen for Strings?

Comment: Unless there is something else to it it's happening for Strings as well

Comment: I was able to circumvent this issue for Strings by writing a custom converter for java.lang.String that sets null values to empty strings. But for Integer (and Date) that's a more difficult task. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it for strings. See the updated answer for the proper fix.